# how to add google analytics code in email

Tags: email, google-analytics

i am looking for a solutions for Google Analytics, can i add Google Analytics in our email.

```
    <div>
    <table width="600" border="0" cellspacing="2" cellpadding="2" style="background-color:#FFF; font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif; font-size:12px;">
    <tr>
    <td height="25" style="text-align:left;">MESSAGE</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td height="25" style="text-align:left;">URL</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td height="25" style="text-align:left;">NEED TO PUT GOOGLE CODE HERE</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <tr>
    <td height="25" style="text-align:right;">Powered by XXX.</td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    </div>
```

Thanks

Comment: @Blexy is on the ball with his comment. The URL builder is your friend here. You are not going to be able to fire traditional GATC JavaScript in your email (for security reasons) if that's what you are suggesting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would append the campaign tracking parameters to the URL. You can use [Google's URL Builder](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1033867?hl=en)  to build these. Essentially, your link would look something like this:

```
 <tr>
    <td height="25" style="text-align:left;">http://example-landing-page.com/test?utm_source=exampleSource&utm_medium=Email&utm_term=awesomeKeyword&utm_content=goodContent&utm_campaign=bestCampaignEver</td>
 </tr>
```